# Woocommerce product search from certain category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can search product from a category by search string and others attribute?

Example:

In movie category, I have 20 product, I want to search for movie category by search string (?s='action' parameter), and others attribute like movie_type=thiller

Answer (score 1):

Parameters accepted by Wordpress search string are listed here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/

For attribute / custom fields, `meta_key` and `meta_value` may be used. So the query in your example should be like

```
http://yoursite.com/?s=action&category_name=movie&meta_key=movie_type&meta_value=thriller
```